# Tin in silver nitrate, any soln color change?

Tags: electrochemistry

I have lab question in which a $\ce{AgNO3}$ solution with a tin strip placed in it is mentioned. This isn't a reaction we actually did in the lab, but due to a color change in the solution of one we did do, I was wondering if there would be any for this reaction. Googling I found that the $\ce{AgNO3}$ solution is initially colorless, but that's all I could find. So would there be for this one, or would the solution remain colorless?

Comment: It would remain colorless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution will remain colourless until silver particles will participated from the solution.

Silver nitrate solution is unstable, its decomposition is accelerated by light:

$\ce{2 AgNO3(l) -> 2 Ag(s) + O2(g) + 2 NO2(g)}$

That will change the color of the solution to brown. After silver participation, the solution will be colorless again.

A tin strip added to the nitrate solution will dissolve into tin(II) nitrate and will consequently react with silver nitrate accordingly:

$\ce{Sn(NO3)2 + 2AgNO3 + H2O -> Sn(OH)4 + 4HNO3 + 2Ag}$

Analogous silver reactions are described by [Tollens' reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent), [mirror preparation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror) and [gelatin silver process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin_silver_process).